# Making the popup always in container

Tags: jquery, popup, hover, offset

I need to make the popup window that is visible when you hover over the image, stay inside the ".container"

So when the popup goes out of the container, the offset should change so that it is on the left side of the cursor so it fits.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aIuAy

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery only for .container for onmouseove and for onmouseout remove that hover popup